# Does AndroLua have a way to process lua scripts from resource files?

Tags: android, lua

Is there a way to pass files like `res/raw/myfile.lua` for loading in `AndroLua`. These files could be then part of the apk at `compile time`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot currently, although this is a good idea and I may get to implement it soon. Also, this question would better go to [AndroLua issues](https://github.com/mkottman/AndroLua/issues).

**Update**:

Now you can load modules from application assets. The project has been updated with an example module `greet.lua` stored in the assets. This was done by creating a custom [Lua module loader](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders) for `require` in Java which uses `AssetManager` to load the module.

Comment: Michal, is it possible to load scripts runtime from the network? I am thinking of reducing my app size. Thanks for the work!

Comment: (Almost) everything is possible... when someone has the time to implement it :) Unfortunately I no longer have the time to maintain AndroLua.

Comment: Michal, I want to thank you from the depth of my heart. This is such a nice implementation. I have been tinkering around the code base you have provided and fortunately I am able to load scripts runtime.

Comment: @MichalKottman would you consider adding me as a collaborator for https://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto or even handing off repo ownership to somone willing to maintain it? Sorry for making this a SO comment but there's no other way to get in touch and github doesn't provide an easy way to do that.